# How to use Scanner in both main and method

Tags: java

I'm trying to get input in both my main and other methods, but I'm not clear on how to get the scanner working in both.

It gives me a weird error:

```
Exception in thread "main"
java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
 at Hwk11.getRainData(Hwk11.java: 28)
 at Hwk11.main(Hwk11.java: 18)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hwk11 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many weeks of data do you have?");
    int numWeeks = stdin.nextInt();
    if (numWeeks <= 0 || numWeeks > 52) {
      System.out.println("Invalid number of weeks.");
    }
    else {
      double[] rainWeeks = new double [numWeeks];
      getRainData(rainWeeks);
      showRain(rainWeeks);
    }
  }

  public static void getRainData(double[] rainFall) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the weekly rainfall for each week.");
    for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++) {
      System.out.println("Week number " + (index + 1) + ":");
      rainFall[index] = stdin.nextDouble();
    }
  }

  public static void showRain(double[] rainFall) {
    for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++) {
      System.out.print(rainFall[index] + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: works fine for me..Can you show what inputs you're supplying?

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` generally means that there are elements in the scanner's stream which match the lookup requirements - in your case, no `double` values. Also, instead of creating a new `Scanner`, simply pass the `Scanner` from the `main` method

Comment: It is working for me too.

Comment: @MadProgrammer how do you pass the scanner?

Comment: @David You could create a static scanner outside the methods (just below public Class Hwk11) static Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in); and remove other decllarations.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it working with a static scanner.

Answer (score 2):

People are saying "works for me".

The problem that the behavior (whether it works or not) depends on exactly how input is provided.

- If you provide input interactively, it will probably work.
- If you provide input by redirecting standard input like this:

  ```
    java Hwk11 < input.txt
  ```

  then it won't.

The problem is that a `Scanner` will read-ahead and buffer any characters available from its input stream.  That is fine normally, but in your code you have created two distinct `Scanner` objects to read from `System.in`.  Thus when standard input is redirected:

- The first `Scanner.nextInt` call will cause most / all of the input to be buffered in the first `Scanner`
- When the second `Scanner` is created and `Scanner.nextDouble` is called, it won't see the input buffered in the first `Scanner` and that will lead to an exception ... when it runs out of input characters "too soon".

The solution is to NOT create multiple `Scanner` objects for the same input stream.  Use one `Scanner` and either put it in a field, or pass it as a parameter to all of the places that it needs to be used.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me. Don't enter anything but a double if you asking for next double so no "2.3 cm", just pass 2.3 and add cm when you print in

I am assuming your `showRain(double[] rainFall)` method probably executes before `getRaindata(double[] rainFall)` is able to finish and populate the array. Array you passsing to `showRain(double[] rainFall)` might be empty.

Try putting your method call for `showRain(double[] rainFall)`  after loop in `getRanData(double[] rainFall)`

Alternitivly try passing the whole Scanner object to method.

```
public static void getRainData(double[] rainFall, Scanner stdin) {
  //Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the weekly rainfall for each week.");
  for (int index = 0; index < rainFall.length; index++) {
    System.out.println("Week number " + (index + 1) + ":");
    rainFall[index] = stdin.nextDouble();
  }
  showRain(rainFall); 
}
```

Don't forget to close it when you done with scanner.

Comment: There is no way showRain executes before getRainData, also putting non-double input would lead into InputMismatchException (not NoSuchElement)

Comment: I just assumed it because random bugs can happen. Forgot to say that in original answer